# Updating children in NHibernate 3.3 in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, nhibernate, datagridview

I've been looking around on how to update the children of a parent entity and couldn't find something that fit my requirements. I'm using a data grid view control to bind these child data into my form and to a DataSet. I need to be able to know which rows in my data grid were modified, deleted, and added so that was why I needed to pass it to a DataSet.

Below are my Parent and Child mappings:

### **Parent: Fees.hbm.xml**

```
<class name="Fees" table="fees">
<id name="Id" column="id">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>
<property name="Code" column="code" />
<property name="Description" column="description" />
<property name="Status" column="status" />
<bag name="FeesDetails" table="fees_lines" inverse="true" cascade="all">
  <key column="fees_id" />
  <one-to-many class="FeesLines" />
</bag>
```

### **Child: FeesLines.hbm.xml**

```
<class name="FeesLines" table="fees_lines">
<id name="Id" column="id">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>
<property name="FeesId" column="fees_id" type="System.Guid" insert="false" update="false" />
<property name="Description" column="description" />
<property name="Amount" column="amount" />

<many-to-one name="Fee" class="Fees" column="fees_id" />
```

I need to be able to update my child records using NHibernate, so how do you do it?

Comment: [Can I Answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer): "If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question..." - but what you shouldn't do is cram it all into the question box. Try to re-write your question **as** a question, and then add your solution as an *answer*

Comment: Oh sorry ok..will do!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do an update for my child records, here's how I did it:

```
public bool UpdateFees(string id, string code, string desc, DataSet details)
    {
        bool success = false;

        using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                Fees fees = (Fees)Session.Get("EnrollmentSystem.Domain.Fees", Guid.Parse(id));
                fees.Code = code;
                fees.Description = desc;

                if (details.HasChanges())
                {
                    if (details.HasChanges(DataRowState.Added))
                    {
                        DataSet tempDataSet = details.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
                        foreach (DataRow row in tempDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            FeesLines lines = new FeesLines();
                            lines.Fee = fees;
                            lines.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                            lines.Description = row["Description"].ToString();
                            lines.Amount = (row["Amount"].ToString() == "") ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(row["Amount"].ToString());
                            fees.FeesDetails.Add(lines);
                            Session.Save(lines);
                        }
                    }

                    if (details.HasChanges(DataRowState.Modified))
                    {
                        DataSet editedSet = details.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
                        foreach (DataRow row in editedSet.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            var item = (from f in fees.FeesDetails
                                        where f.Id.Equals(Guid.Parse(row["Id"].ToString()))
                                        select f).SingleOrDefault();
                            if (item != null)
                            {
                                item.Description = row["Description"].ToString();
                                item.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Amount"].ToString());
                                Session.SaveOrUpdate(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (details.HasChanges(DataRowState.Deleted))
                    {
                        DataSet deleted = details.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);

                        for (int row = 0; row < deleted.Tables[0].Rows.Count; row++ )
                        {
                            var item = (from f in fees.FeesDetails
                                        where f.Id.Equals(Guid.Parse(deleted.Tables[0].Rows[row][0, DataRowVersion.Original].ToString()))
                                        select f).SingleOrDefault();
                            if (item != null)
                            {
                                fees.FeesDetails.Remove(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Session.SaveOrUpdate(fees);

                transaction.Commit();
                success = transaction.WasCommitted;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }

        return success;
    }
```

I created a function where I passed the new values for the parent data, and passed my DataSet that held the new/modified/deleted set of children.